# Prevent Modal Dialog on win32 process crash

Tags: c++, winapi

We have a legacy build infrastructure for nightly builds (implemented in Perl) to compile, link and unit tests our applications/plugins. On Windows, if the unit testing process crashes, this pops up a Modal Dialog which "locks" our build farm.

Is there a way (win32 API call, system config, env var, something...) to disable this behavior to have the child process terminate immediately on crashes, with no Modal Dialog and a non-zero exit status instead?

Thanks, --DD

PS: We compile with SEC (Structured Exception Handling) on Windows, to be able to "catch" crashes using catch (...), therefore avoiding this issue most of the time, but sometime that's not enough, since of course some crashes are not recoverable (if they corrupted the stack for example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on who's throwing the dialog, you may have to combine multiple approaches.

```
    SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
```

...will shut up one set of dialogs.

Comment: You can combine them as this: SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);

Comment: Not only can you combine them, you need to combine them; the flags don't stack, you're losing the first one when you set the second one

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an 'unhandled exception handler' that catches all exceptions: put a call to SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(handler) in your initialisation code and it'll call the handler routine. Really simple.

I use sample code from an old article, include a file called [minidumper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx?msg=2583295), call the exposed function, and you're done.

[Here's some more example code](http://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/), this pops a different dialog, but you can change that to simply write a message to a log file or similar.

If you're writing a pure .NET app, then you'll be more interested in [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/errorhandling/article.php/c5905/).

Comment: Segfaults are not caught by exception handlers.

Comment: @IanThompson what do you mean? Segfault on Windows? you mean one of those 0xc000005 'access denied' errors?

Comment: Yes, anything where a signal is raised rather than an exception thrown. E.g. class A { public: int b;} ; A* nu_a = NULL; nu_a->b = 5;  Will give you: Access violation writing location 0x00000000. Which is not an exception and won't be caught by any exception handler.

Comment: @IanThompson access violations like that are 0xc0000005 errors. These may not be caught by C++ exception handler but will if you enable SEH. Memory violations like that require OS specific handlers, on Windows SEH. Try compiling with /EHa if you use VC++.

Comment: not quite. __try and __catch will handle those errors with the /EHa switch, but SEH has it's own problems. It is a matter of personal preference, but I personally prefer that the process be terminated, but without a modal dialog being raised. i.e. the SetErrorMode solution above.

Comment: @IanThompson I prefer to catch those using a SetUnhandledException, write a minidump and abort when these are raised. Then I post-mortem diagnose the crash... which is what I put in the answer. No modal dialogs involved.

Comment: Useful for diagnosis, but not so much as an exception/error handling strategy. In certain applications, there are a class of user generated errors that are better remedied in user-space because of the performance implications of handling them in the application. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/09/10/228068.aspx

Comment: @IanThompson, `int* p = NULL; *p = 1;`  is plain segfault. signal.h and SIGSEGV signal hanglers in plain C will catch this, without crashing. SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() is Windows Kernel functionality that will catch ALL sorts of exception, including the segfault! Try it yourself.

Comment: The question was not about catching exceptions or errors, but clearly about preventing the modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use the "catch(...)" statement because then you can miss the point of having unit tests.
2. What you need is a non-modal dialog, since the modal dialogs are for blocking the user from any further actions and the program execution (in your case the unit test runs) hangs up until the user makes his/her choice. Now the crash dialogs can't be avoided, but you need to see how your unit test framework handles these situations. I would say you missed something around the unit testing framework because if I have a crash in my applications I got just a log message about that from the Boost.Test stubs.

If you run your unit tests as a child process it shouldn't block your build bot, BUT: if a unit test case fails, you shouldn't continue the building process in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [WSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) to "script" your windows.

With it you can "simulate" that somebody clicked on the "Accept" button of the modal window, or send the ESC key to close that.

Regards.