# Programmatically restart application when it crashes

Tags: c++, windows

I have a Windows application written in C++ that sometimes crashes. Is there a way to programmatically ignore the modal dialog box and automatically relaunch the application?

Comment: An alternate solution ... figure out why it crashes sometimes and fix the problem!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Modal Dialog on win32 process crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861506/prevent-modal-dialog-on-win32-process-crash)

Comment: The statistics package S-Plus used to leak memory horribly and its solution was exactly this. When it thought it was close to the edge it would store away its state, restart, restore state and continue. Needless to say, this was not a well-regarded solution by the userbase! Follow Praetorian's advice and fix the disease rather than devising a cure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a look at the [RegisterApplicationRestart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (Windows Vista/2008 minimum)

Answer (score 5):

Something i've learned from viruses: use a service to check that your application is running. If the service detects that the application is not running, start the application. Implement the service however you like.

Comment: Very, very good. The service does not even have to be an actual service either, just another program.

Comment: if you've ever tried getting a virus scanner removed from your machine, you'll be able to see quite a few parallels, yes

Answer (score 0):

Write an unhandled exception handler that relaunches. If you need to be sure you have the memory to do so, preallocate.

If you make recovering from faults too much a guaranteed thing, you risk never fixing the faults.

Plus, it's better to notify someone that it faulted and shutdown. What if you faulted on a problem that will reoccur every time the program starts. Then it looks like your program is always running, but it isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

in vc++:

```
//-- a Top-level Exception Handler in process level 
LONG WINAPI TopLevelExceptionHandler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExceptionInfo)
{

// find app name to re execute it.
TCHAR szPath[_MAX_PATH];
VERIFY(::GetModuleFileName(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance, szPath, _MAX_PATH));
CString csPath(szPath);

// re execute.
ShellExecute( NULL, "open",csPath , NULL, NULL, 1 );

//
exit(-1);
return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}


main()
{
   //set a Top-level Exception Handler in process level to re execute app. 
   SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(TopLevelExceptionHandler);
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation of how/why this helps.